# filter_input with invalid filter

Tags: php

I just came across this snippet in our code base:

```
$token = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'token', FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING);
if ($token === false || $token === null) {
    die('invalid token');
}
```

`FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING` is not a valid filter type.  Does that mean it would just revert to `FILTER_DEFAULT`, as an unrecognized filter has been passed in?

Comment: find the coder and beat them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All GET and POST vars are strings, and as you have noted `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING` is not a defined constant.  If you enable error reporting you will see:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING - assumed 'FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING'
>
> Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

So `filter_input()` will return `NULL` just like any other function that is not passed required arguments.

This is assuming that whoever wrote this did not also define `FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING`.

Comment: Good to know that invalid args, return NULL, I was not aware of that. In this case then, that die() would always be triggered, which makes me wonder if this code is even used anymore. Thanks

Comment: @bumperbox pretty much everything returns NULL in php, if a value isn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a warning that an undefined constant is being used, and PHP will go ahead and turn it into a string literal. The best thing to do is use a constant that is defined in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).